# File upload related to checkbox in PHP

Tags: php, file, checkbox

How do I link the file input type with the checkbox?

This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[0]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]"> checkbox 1 <br />
<input type="file" name="file_upload[1]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]"> checkbox 2 <br />
<input type="file" name="file_upload[2]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]"> checkbox 3 <br />
<input type="file" name="file_upload[3]"  /> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]"> checkbox 4 <br />
```

Now I need to check in PHP when a file is uploaded the correspondent checkbox is checked (preferably with a loop), but I can't make it work.

This is what I have in PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file_upload[1]']) && isset($_FILES['checkbox[1]']))  {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES` won't contain your checkboxes. It's either in `$_POST` or in `$_GET` depending on your form method.

Comment: @PLB It's probably `$_POST`; you can't upload files with `$_GET`. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your checkbox input tag to  `<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" value="1" >`

i.e. you need to add missing `value=""` attribute

and as mentioned in the comment

you need to check `if(isset($_POST['checkbox'][0])) {`  instead in `$_FILES`

Try printing both `print_r($_FILES)` `and print_r($_POST)` ... this should give you idea of what structure of data you are receiving after submitting

You can just loop through the file_uploaded array and then check if related checbox index is set.

Answer (score 1):

The loop you need should be organized like this: 'for each element of `$_FILES['file_upload']` array check the corresponding (with the same index) element of `$_POST['checkbox']`. For example:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file_upload'])) { ... process 'no files sent' case ... }

$files_total = count($_FILES['file_upload']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $files_total; ++$i) {
  if ( $_FILES['file_upload'][$i] && !empty( $_POST['checkbox'][$i] ) ) {
    // .. do something
  }
  else {
    // .. do something else
  }
}
```